# Edit numbers until sum value has reached

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to have a VBA macro that will help me to edit values in the column 'C' for each row until the sum value has reached.
However, there are some criteria:

- The value has to be smaller than the value in column 'B'
- If the value in column 'B' is zero, then the value in column 'C' should be zero

For example:

I have certain values in column A for each row and I want the **sum for Column C to be 10**. Hence, the VBA will loop and iterate each row in column C and check if the number in Column B is greater than 0, if yes then it will add 1 to it. After going through each row, it will check the sum, if the sum has not reach the certain amount (in this case, it's 10), it will loop back again and add 1 to each row and stop when it reaches the sum.

Example output:

```
----------------------
Column B  | Column C
----------------------
  124     |     3
  100     |     3
  83      |     2
  23      |     1
  4       |     1
  0       |     0
-----------------------
```

Code:

```
Sub Loop()
Dim Report As Worksheet
Set Report = Excel.ActiveSheet

Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim total As Integer

total = Range("C8").Value
Range("C2:C7").ClearContents

For total = 0 To 10
 For Each cell In Range("C2:C12")
    For i = 2 To 7
        If Range("B" & i).Value > 0 Then
            cell.Value = cell.Value + 1
            If cell.Value > Range("B" & i).Value Then
                cell.Value = cell.Value
            End If
        Else:
            cell.Value = 0
        End If

        Next i
 Next cell
 total = total + Range("C8").Value

Next total

End Sub
```

However, the output that I got seems to be not my desire output and I got all zeros instead. I am a newbie to VBA :(, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You do understand that `i = 2` and `total = Range(...).Value` is completely redundant since you are using both variables in a `For ... Loop`, right?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs the reason I put ```i =2``` is because I want it to loop through the column B starting from the 2nd row. Is that correct?

Comment: You already have `For i = 2 To 7`. This is what sets the starting value of `i`. You could place `i = 4000` and it will still start at __2__ when it hits your loop.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs yep I have changed the value ```i = 4000``` but it seems like the output is still 0 for all the rows

Comment: I stated it was redundant (as in those two lines mean absolutely nothing in your code), not that it was the issue you're having.

Comment: You missed the point being made by @K.Dᴀᴠɪs. The line that says `i = 2` (or `i = 4000` or `i = anythingelse` can be deleted, because it does absolutely nothing. The `for i = 2 to 7` throws away the previous assignment to `i`, so `i = 2` is a wasted line of do-nothing code and should be deleted completely.

Comment: First you need to change the name of the sub because Loop is not a legal name. Then I suggest you step through this code line by line in the debugger and figure out what it's actually doing. I especially recommend you think about whether you actually need the **for 1 = 2 to 7** loop inside the **for each cell . . .** loop. Maybe also ponder what exactly the line **cell.value = cell.value** is doing. Lots to keep you busy. Let us know if you have any more specific questions.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs i see! i got that as ```i=2``` will be overwritten by the codes below

Comment: The [`Range.Offset()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) property will be useful to read and understand also - it will allow you to, say, loop through your cells in column C and do things with other rows/columns based on the current column C cell that is targeted...

Answer (score 1):

Below is my take on your problem but a couple of things to start...

- VBA didn't much like the sub having the name loop as loop is a reserved word
- I've used methods intersect and offset when working with ranges but there are multiple ways to skin this cat
- Range("C2:C7").ClearContents will result in empty cells and while an empty cell will likely be considered 0 when trying to add 1 to the value, it would perhaps be better to give the cells an explicit value e.g. 0
- There exists some cases where a total of, for example, 10 can't be reached and if not tested for and handled, the loop will run forever, never reaching 10
- I'm not sure if msgbox is appropriate to your task but I popped it in anyway in case you haven't yet come across it

```
Sub SomeLoop()
    Set totalCell = Range("C8")
    Set editableColumnRange = Range("C2:C7")
    
    'set all the editable cells to a default/initial value
    editableColumnRange.Value = 0
    
    totalAtEndOfLastLoop = 0
    total = 0
    Offset = 0
    Do While total < 10
        'set the current row to the current row offset past the top row of the editable cells
        Set currentRowRange = editableColumnRange.Rows(1).EntireRow.Offset(Offset)
        Set currentCCell = Intersect(currentRowRange, Range("C:C"))
        Set currentBCell = Intersect(currentRowRange, Range("B:B"))
        
        'implement the rules
        If currentBCell.Value = 0 Then
            currentCCell.Value = 0
        ElseIf currentBCell.Value > currentCCell.Value + 1 Then
            'to ensure b remains > c, we need to test b > c + 1
            'so if c is incremented by 1, it remains less than b
            currentCCell.Value = currentCCell.Value + 1
            total = total + 1
        End If
        
        Offset = Offset + 1
        If Offset >= editableColumnRange.Rows.Count Then
            'we've got an offset which would task us past the data
            'it's time to wrap around
            
            'check if the total has changed otherwise we'll be stuck in the loop forever
            If total > totalAtEndOfLastLoop Then
                totalAtEndOfLastLoop = total
                Offset = 0
            Else
                MsgBox "The total hasn't changed"
                Exit Do
            End If
            
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow thanks! The solution above works well in this case! :D

Answer (score 0):

### Increment While Less Than

[image]

- Adjust the values in the constants section and the worksheets (possibly workbooks).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub doIncrement()
    
    ' Constants
    Const sFirst As String = "B2"
    Const dFirst As String = "C2"
    Const iTotal As Long = 10
    
    ' Worksheets (could be different)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ActiveSheet
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ActiveSheet
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Range.
    Dim srg As Range
    With sws.Range(sFirst)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set srg = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    ' Write values from Source Range to Source Array.
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim sData As Variant
    If rCount = 1 Then
        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData = srg.Value
    Else
        sData = srg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Define Destination Array.
    Dim dData() As Long: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1) ' Long: all zeros
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim dTotal As Long
    
    ' Loop through rows of Source Array and write to rows of Destination Array.
    Do
        For r = 1 To rCount
            If sData(r, 1) - dData(r, 1) > 1 Then
                dData(r, 1) = dData(r, 1) + 1
                dTotal = dTotal + 1
                If dTotal = iTotal Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
            End If
        Next r
    Loop

    With dws.Range(dFirst)
        ' Write values from Destination Array to Destination Range.
        .Resize(rCount).Value = dData
        ' Clear contents below.
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - rCount + 1) _
            .Offset(rCount).ClearContents
    End With
    
End Sub
```